# Necessary conditions for $A=K+\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Consider the homomorphism between a field $K$ and $A$ which is finitely generated $K$-algebra (that is it can be written $K[x_1,...,x_n]$). If $\phi: A \to K$ is a homomorphism between $K$-algebras does it always hold that $A=K+\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)$?

I have never encountered this rule so what are sufficient conditions for this to hold?

Comment: One sufficient condition would be the conditions necessary to apply the splitting lemma. The splitting lemma tells you that if you have a short exact sequence:

$$ 0 \to \mathrm{Ker}(\phi) \xrightarrow{i} A \xrightarrow{\phi} K \to 0$$

then $A$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $K$ and $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$ if there exists an algebra homomorphism $t:K \to A$ such that $\phi \circ t$ is the identity on $K$.

Comment: In my case, given that K is algebraic closed field then what mapping fullfills these conditions? If the group of homomorphism were cyclic then we were done but that's not in general the case.

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head and right now I don't have time to think. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @MattN.: but the question is not about *direct sum*, but rather simple internal sum.

Comment: @tomasz Great, thanks for your comment, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @MattN. In reference to your first comment, there is clearly such a map $t$: it is just the inclusion $K\hookrightarrow A$. In fact $A=K+\ker\phi$ is direct as vector spaces but not algebras.

Comment: @seaturtles Thank you for your comment. But it is not clear to me why the inclusion map is an inverse of $\phi$.

Comment: @MattN. The map $\phi$ restricted to the subset $K\subset A$ is the identity (since it's $K$-linear). By the way, did you test to see if was an inverse? Stated in generality: If $Y\subseteq X$ is any subset and $f:X\to Y$ restricted to $Y$ is the identity, then the inclusion $Y\hookrightarrow X$ is a right inverse of $f$. This is set-theoretic fact is pretty straightforward to verify.

Comment: @seaturtles I kept re-reading this to see the mistake but there seems to be none. What is puzzling me is: wouldn't this mean that every algebra homomorphism is the identity?

Comment: I see you edited your previous comment.

Comment: @MattN Why would that mean every algebra homomorphism is the identity? (The original version of my comment was also correct and said basically the same thing, I just decided on a different way to communicate.)

Comment: Wait, let me read the edited comment.

Comment: @seaturtles I read your previous comment as "given any algebra  homo. $\phi : A \to B$ then $\phi(a) = \phi(a1) = a \phi(1) = a$". Of course, this doesn't even make sense unless $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: @MattN. If $\phi:A\to B$ is a homomorphism of unital $K$-algebras then $\phi(ax)=a\phi(x)$ for all $a\in K$ and $x\in A$.

Comment: @seaturtles Yes. But in my previous comment $a$ was an element of the algebra not the the underlying field : )

Comment: Okay, in which case I don't see the relevance...

Comment: Exactly. Me neither. : )

Comment: @tomasz What's the difference between direct sum and "simple internal sum"? Doesn't $X=A \oplus B$ imply $X = A + B$ if $A,B$ are subrings of some $X$?

Comment: @MattN.: Yes, but certainly not the converse. For instance, we always have $X=X+X$, but never $X=X\oplus X$ internally (unless you admit trivial rings; though externally it may occasionally be true, i.e. we may have that $X\cong X\oplus X$).

Comment: @tomasz Yes but your first comment implies that my first comment does not pertain. Now I am thinking that it does: if you can apply the splitting lemma it is a possible answer to the question. No?

Comment: @MattN.: Well, it's not irrelevant per se, but the condition that $A$ is a *direct sum* of the kernel and $K$ is, at a glance, much stronger than merely being the sum, so any necessary condition for that is probably much too strong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $a\in A$ we can write $a=\underbrace{\phi(a)}_{\in\,K}+\underbrace{a-\phi(a)}_{\in\,\ker\phi}$.

More generally if $\phi$ is a surjective map out of $R$, and its restriction to the subset $S\subseteq R$ is also onto, then we can write $R=S+\ker\phi$ by the same reasoning. A similar proposition holds for groups, where $\phi$ is surjective out of $G$ and also onto restricted to a subset $X\subseteq G$, then $G=X\ker\phi$.

Comment: In you answer is $R$ a commutative ring or an algebra over a field? I assume you assume $\phi: R\to K$ for some field $K$. I don't want to bother you, it's just really not 100% clear to me.

Comment: @MattN. In my second paragraph I assume that $R$ and $S$ are arbitrary rings. In fact, the claim for rings *follows* from the claim for groups, by considering the underlying additive groups of the rings and totally ignoring their multiplicative structure. This means we are not assuming the rings are commutative, or that they are algebras over fields, or that they are even unital or associative - the multiplicative structure is totally irrelevant. Of course, rings are abelian as additive groups, and my claim for groups holds for nonabelian ones, so it is more general still.

Comment: Can you prove my proposition for groups? It follows the same idea - given an arbitrary element of the domain, invoke an element of the special subset that shares the same image with it, then their difference will be a fudge factor in the kernel. I think it is instructive.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will get back to you, right now (for the next few hours) something else is keeping me from thinking about this.

Comment: Yes, I can prove it. That is: I don't think there is much to prove especially given your answer and your comment.